# ng-mouseleave but with Keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In angular we have `ng-mouseleave` where if I have it in a div/button or whatever element then it triggers the action when the mouse leaves. Lets say I have that for a selection..

After I select a text with my mouse, I call the function given by the ng-mouseleave directive.

Is there a way that I can achieve the same thing using the keyboard? lets say I don't have a mouse and I select something with the keyboard and I want to trigger a function as I am selecting some text within a div.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you looking for `ng-blur`? I am not sure what you mean by "I select something with the keyboard and I want to trigger a function as I am selecting some text within a div" - how would you select plain text within a div without a cursor of some kind? You could tab through buttons & links, however, in which case `ng-blur` would fire.

Comment: Not sure how you plan to select something with the keyboard. Perhaps by using the "find in page " option or tabs. You'll have to be more specific

Comment: is this `angular` or `angularjs` ? it can only be one and you have tagged both.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You could call `document.selection.createRange().text` in your text selection keyboard trigger. If you're selecting things with the keyboard, I'm assuming you have some keybindings e.g. cursor keys for movement, enter or space for "start selecting/end selecting". So this "end selection" event - that's your trigger. If you show the code you're using to select text with keyboard, you might get a more specific answer.